# cannot implicitly convert type error when using aliases

Tags: c#, .net, generics, alias

I am new to learning C# and am coming from a C++ background. I am using an alias in the following manner:

```
using CreationFunction = Func<Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2, GAShooter.Entity>;
```

Then in my class I have a dictionary like so:

```
private Dictionary<String, CreationFunction> creators;
```

However when I try to initialize it in the contstructor like this:

```
creators = new Dictionary<String, CreationFunction>();
```

I get an error.  It says that it cannot implicitly convert the type.  What gives?

EDIT: full code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using CreationFunction = Func<Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2, GAShooter.Entity>;

namespace GAShooter
{
    class EntityFactory
    {
        private Dictionary<String, CreationFunction> creators;

        public EntityFactory()
        {
            creators = new Dictionary<String, CreationFunction>();
        }

        public void RegisterCreator(String name, CreationFunction function)
        {
            creators[name] = function;
        }

        public Entity Create(String name)
        {
            var creator = creators[name];
            return creator();
        }
    }
}
```

and the full text for the error is:

> cannot implicitly convert type `'Dictionary<string,Func <Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2, GAShooter.Entity>` to type `'Dictionary<String, CreationFunction>'`

Comment: What's the full text of the error? That should work.

Comment: Provide the exact text of the error message, and also a code example that's complete and demonstrates the described issue.

Comment: @RufusL Please be sure your edits do not make the question worse, by transforming it in to a quote you removed the ability to see what was in the < > tags.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain oh, thank you - I will watch for that!

Comment: @user3355098 Your example is still a poor one. It requires the answerer to have XNA installed and readly to use. You could easily create a toy console program that used `Func<object, object>` and demonstrated the same problem and would be 100's of times easier for other users to copy in to VS and just run.

Comment: on which line the error occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is in your alias definition, you should change it to

```
using CreationFunction = System.Func<Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2, GAShooter.Entity>;
```

> Create a using alias to make it easier to qualify an identifier to a
>   namespace or type. The right side of a using alias directive must
>   always be a fully-qualified type regardless of the using directives
>   that come before it.

read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).

Comment: @user3355098: Or move the alias inside your `namespace`